# Is there a list of MySQL configuration directives?

Tags: mysql

I was just browsing through the MySQL 5.1 manual, looking for a nice list of configuration directives and their explanation, and I cannot find any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should contain what you are looking for: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html